# What do double colons with parameter expansion do?

Tags: bash, shell, openssl

What does `subjectAltName = ${ENV::subjectAltName}` in a shell script mean? I've tried this locally on MacOS and it just returns null.

I've gone to various tutorials on bash scripting and I have found that something like

```
subjectAltName = ${ENV:-subjectAltName}
```

would mean if `ENV` is unset or null, the expansion of `subjectAltName` is substituted. Otherwise, the value of `ENV` is substituted but I have not seen double colons in the context of parameter expansion. See [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) for that tutorial. Also [here](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe).

I've also seen this usage:

```
$ENV::HOME/.rnd
```

Here, I expect a concatenation for whatever these variables are.

This is used for an `openssl.conf` file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not shell syntax, it's a feature unique to `openssl.conf` and the OpenSSL CONF library. The [config(5) man page](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man5/config.html) says:

> It is also possible to substitute a value from another section using the syntax `$section::name` or `${section::name}`. By using the form `$ENV::name` environment variables can be substituted.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone coming across this question via searching "Bash parameter expansion double colon", note that `${VAR::N}` would be valid shell syntax if `N` is a number, meaning "create a substring from the first `N` characters of `$VAR`".

From `man bash`:

> `${parameter:offset}`
>
> `${parameter:offset:length}`
>
> Substring Expansion.  Expands to up to length characters of the value of parameter starting at the character specified by offset.  If parameter is @ or *, an indexed array subscripted by @ or *, or an associative array name, the results differ as described below.  If length is omitted, expands to the substring of the value of parameter starting at the character specified by offset and extending to the end of the value.  length and offset are arithmetic expressions (see ARITHMETIC EVALUATION below).
>
> If  offset  evaluates to a number less than zero, the value is used as an offset in characters from the end of the value of parameter.  If length evaluates to a number less than zero, it is interpreted as an offset in characters from the end of the value of parameter rather than a number of characters, and the expansion is the characters between offset and that result.  Note that a negative offset must be separated from the colon by at least one space to avoid being confused with the :- expansion.
>
> If parameter is @ or *, the result is length positional parameters beginning at offset.  A negative offset is taken relative to one greater than the greatest positional parameter, so an offset of -1 evaluates to the last positional parameter.  It is an expansion error if length evaluates to a number less than zero.
>
> If parameter is an indexed array name subscripted by @ or *, the result is the length members of the array beginning with ${parameter[offset]}.  A negative offset is taken relative to one greater than the maximum index of the specified array.  It is an expansion error if length evaluates to a number less than zero.
>
> Substring expansion applied to an associative array produces undefined results.
>
> Substring indexing is zero-based unless the positional parameters are used, in which case the indexing starts at 1 by default.  If offset is 0, and the positional parameters are used, $0 is prefixed to the list.

The behaviour when `offset` is an empty string isn't clearly documented, but from simple experimentation we can tell that `${VAR::N}` is equivalent to `${VAR:0:N}`. Indeed, there are existing examples of such usage (e.g. [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php?title=Python_package_guidelines&oldid=803011#Source)).

Comment: *"isn't clearly documented"* -> "isn't documented". (see `man bash` following `${parameter:offset:length}` in Parameter Expansion). Interesting the Arch Wiki has examples. It would take confirming with the bash source code that there are no corner cases that may have undefined results before having any comfort level with the undocumented use of the substring expansion.

Comment: Since *offset* and *length* are arithmetic expressions, `N` doesn't even really have to be a number; it can also be something that can evaluate to a number, which is . . . pretty flexible. In the OP's example (`${ENV::subjectAltName}`), `subjectAltName` will be interpreted as a variable-name, and the contents of that variable will be interpreted as an arithmetic expression. (If the variable isn't set, then it will evaluate to zero.)

Comment: I also partly agree with @DavidC.Rankin's point. The documentation clearly indicates that when a variable is the empty string, its integer value is zero; but it isn't so clear IMHO about the integer value of an empty arithmetic expression. I would expect it to work, but describing it as "valid shell syntax" is probably overstating the case!